# I have a file upload system that renames the file and gives you the link for your file, but will not give file link

Tags: php, file, hyperlink, upload, rename

I have a file upload system that renames the file and gives you the file link, but will not give the right file link, it will just give you the name of the file you uploaded not what PHP named it.

Here is the [live link](http://testserver1234.no-ip.org/Upload-System/)

Here is my Code :

```
<?php
$fileName = $_FILES["file1"]["name"];
$path_part = pathinfo($fileName);
$fileName = uniqid(md5_file($fileName)).".".$path_part['extension'];

$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"]; 
$fileType = $_FILES["file1"]["type"];
$fileSize = $_FILES["file1"]["size"];
$fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["file1"]["error"];
if (!$fileTmpLoc) {
    echo "ERROR: Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button.";
    exit();
}

if(file_exists('uploads/' . $_FILES['file1']['name'])){
    die('File with that name already exists.');
}

if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "uploads/$fileName")){

 echo "Your File Link<input value='http://testserver1234.no-ip.org/Upload-System/uploads/".  basename( $_FILES['file1']['name']).
    "' style='width: 100%'>";

} else {
    echo "move_uploaded_file function failed";
}
?>
```

What is the mistake I have done. And How can I correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uploads/$fileName is the new file that needs to be returned, while you are using  basename( $_FILES['file1']['name']

Replace

```
echo "Your File Link<input value='http://testserver1234.no-ip.org/Upload-System/uploads/".  basename( $_FILES['file1']['name']).
"' style='width: 100%'>";
```

With

```
 echo "Your File Link<input value='http://testserver1234.no-ip.org/Upload-System/uploads/".  $fileName .
"' style='width: 100%'>";
```